# cant play audio using Ipython.display.Audio in Pycharm, but works in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, audio, jupyter-notebook, pycharm

when I try in Pycharm to play an audio sound using the following code, it doesn't work. the code finishes without error, but nothing happens.
the same code works in Jupyter notebook and will create a small interface to play the audio sound. How can I make it work in Pycharm as well?

below is the code that works in Jupyter notebook

```
import numpy as np
import IPython.display as ipd
seconds=1
sample_rate=4000
t=np.arange( int(seconds*sample_rate) ) / sample_rate
x=np.sin(2*np.pi*440*t)
sound=ipd.display(ipd.Audio(data=x, rate=sample_rate))
```